# Failed to mkdir on remote file server

Tags: java

I have a file server, we can save file by share folder as `\\fileserver\shareFolder`. I can call java api using `file.mkdirs()` to create a folder on this file server by standalone java application, but failed to do same thing by servlet application which is deployed on WebSphere . I really don't understand why, so please help me!

```
File outFile = new File("\\\\fileserver\\shareFolder\\newFolder"); 
if(!outFile.exists()){   
  boolean b = outFile.mkdirs(); //I always got false, actually this work fine before, don't know why doesn't work recently.
}
```

Note: It work fine for local folder (e.g "d:\testfolder\subfolder")

Comment: you might not have access to the folder.

Comment: I have, I have checked it. You know I can do it by standalone java application.

Comment: No any error, you know calling file.mkdirs , just get true or false, I got false.

Comment: code as : File outFile = new File(sessionPath);
      if(!outFile.exists()){      boolean b = outFile.mkdirs(); //I always got false, actually this work fine before, don't know why doesn't work recently.
   }

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please don't post code in comments. Use [[edit]] option to add it to your question.

Comment: what is the servlet running under? is there any security restrictions? are you trying to run the standalone application as the same user/ security policy as the servlet container?

Comment: I am running servelet on WebSphere. The function always work fine before, no any changes recently. From yesterday, failed work with unknown reason.

Comment: What is the value of `sessionPath`?

Comment: You need to provide more details in order for people to be able to help you.  Where is your _servlet application_ running?  Is it on a machine that knows about the file server?  What is the value of _sessionPath_? There are so many variables here and you've provided almost no information...

Comment: Don't mind the sessionPath, it's just a fold path like \\fileserver\sharefolder.  Just I mention above ,I run the servelet on Webspere, and I have run same function and work fine in standalone java application.

Comment: is webshere running as the same user the standalone application. what do the file system permissions look like for all directories in the path.

Comment: Yes, they are in same windows session. We have write and read permissions for the FS

Comment: Yes, I have answered it as above. They are in same windows session.

Comment: Of course, they are same jvm.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/79042/Websphere/Shared-Drive-access-WebSphere) will help.  You might also try using forward slashes in stead of backslashes... Forward slashes tend to work better on more platforms (the Java File API works fine with forward slashes in a Windows environment).

Comment: Thanks! My application is back. The reason is the WAS has upgraded from 6.1 to 7 by another guy, but the WAS has been configured for Windows' service, maybe the logon user is different, so I remove the service and restart WAS by command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your applet to be granted write permissions to the file system.

Comment: Who said anything about applets?  Servlets run **on** the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Folder:Try this:

```
if(!outFile.isDirectory()){   
boolean b = outFile.mkdirs();
}
```

If you are creating a File:

```
String imageFileName = "myImg";
File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    outFile);
```